# Stuck in understanding following initialization way of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

A class is defined as follows:

```
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A(int n) : data{new int[n],default_delete<int[]>()}{}
    shared_ptr<int> data;
};
```

So how to understand `data{new int[n],default_delete<int[]>()}`. The initialization way `data{}` is strange to me since I am not familiar with C++11.  To my understanding, whether this way means letting `data` pointing to consecutive heap memory first then defining the way freeing this memory as `delete int[]` instead of  `delete int`?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Semi-related: [Read up on `std::make_shared`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use one the `std::shared_ptr's` constructors (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)):

```
template< class Y, class Deleter > 
shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d );
```

Where `default_delete` has specialization for array (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete)).

Comment: But in this case the definition of shared_ptr missed the second template parameter(it should be `shared_ptr<int,default_delete<int[]> data` as you said)

Comment: @Finley, no `std::shared_ptr` has only one template parameter. The constructor has two.